# Getting sqlcmd output into a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, parsing, sqlcmd

I am designing an ASP.NET website that will run sqlcmd, get some output and put this into a grid on screen.

I was wondering if there is a method for reading the results of a query from sqlcmd into some kind of format that I can work with, XML, DataSet etc.

Is there a friendly switch in sqlcmd that will output it in a nice format or will I have to parse it myself?

Comment: Are you actually talking about calling Process.Start on sqlcmd.exe? Why not just use ADO.NET (i.e. System.Data.*)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader() function. It will return the object of type XmlReader.

You may get little help [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/SqlCommandExecuteXmlReader.htm) about ExecuteXmlReader().